# How to make Login as Default route in ASP.NET CORE 5.0 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to load Login Page in the first start when application is load.
So far What I try

**Configure**

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    //pattern: "{area=Manager}/{controller=Ticket}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                    pattern: "{area=Manager}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

**ConfigureServices**

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
                options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```

This method works fine, but after user click Login button nothing happened. The Login Page in againg loaded.
SO far I check couple of post here but whatever I check it is releted to `.NET CORE 2.0` and `CORE 2.1`
Any idea what is the problem here ?

Comment: Inside the `Configure` method, in `app.UseEndpoint` you specify what is the default page via a pattern. In you case you have pattern set as `{area=Manager}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}`. This is a reflection on URL. for example: `localhost/user/account/get` area would be `user`, controller, would be `AccountController` and the method, inside the said controller, that is being executed is `get`. Now if you just go to `localhost` the default controller, and method, area, etc, is executed based on the pattern `controller=Home`. Change `Home` to your Login Controller

Comment: @Lith Adding in app.UseEndPoint like 
`pattern: "{area=Identity}/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");` 
doesn't work if you mean like this

Comment: Does your `Login` method return a view? Action `Login` more sounds like a method to use when actually validating the user inserted data for login rather then getting a Login page.

Comment: Yes, it return `View`. I use `ASP.NET CORE MVC Identity` and by default it is added as `RazorPages`. And I want in first app load Login page to be display not HomePage or anything else

Comment: So whenever the URL is plain like `localhost` you wish to load a login page so a user has to fill in data, similar to what facebook does, or did, right? In that case in `ConfigureServices` try out `services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>{ 
 options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Account/Login", ""); });`, or controller and action based on your case. Found the info at https://exceptionnotfound.net/setting-a-custom-default-page-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/ could help out.

Comment: Yes, I did. But doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Routes are supposed to redirect people to a common page (like index.* or start.*, etc.) where the user is able to navigate from and do their stuff.

Setting up a login page for that seems wrong to me, because you are not able to do anything else there, but to login and authenticate.

You stated, that you want to always show the login page before anything else happens, then I guess your application is totally secured and no action or function is available without a valid login.

If this is the case, then simply require an Authorization on every single page, that redirects you then automatically to your login screen. You can use [Authorize] attribute for that or even configure it globally inside the Configure method:
`endpoints.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();`

hint: haven't checked this if it works, some searches against "asp.net mvc global authorization" might help here

Comment: I get the point about redirect that why I want to be loaded in first load. My application needs to be secure and `Users` aren't available to do anything before login. I alredy setup `Authorize` in every Controller action but this is not a case. I want Login be as default page load, nothing more nothing else. I try I couple of method but unfortunetlly nothing works, that why I am asking. 
Setting `endpoints.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();` is not solution for me !

Answer (score 1):

This solution work for me

**ConfigureServices**

```
 services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
                options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
            });
```

**Configure**

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{area=Manager}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();
            });
```